# CBS All Access Streaming Issues

Tags: google-chrome, streaming, drm

[EDIT]: I've ported this over the the Linux & Unix SE - since, I really don't know if the issue is Ubuntu specific or a general Linux/*nix issue. Here's the URL:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563781/known-issues-with-cbs-all-access-streaming

I saw another post had been removed by the moderator on this very same issue.

The little that the google preview showed, seems to be similar enough to my issue. I've re-installed and updated the chrome Widevine DRM plugin; I've used the chrome dev tools to try to figure out what's going on, and I've tried streaming with Firefox; and all I'm getting is a repeating 400 bad request from the player.

I'm guessing this is a linux / ubuntu issue - yes?

Does CBS All Access not even support linux/ubuntu?

Am I missing something? Are you going to downvote me and close my question as well? Who knows.

Comment: Something must have changed on the CBS website because this used to work. On the Mint forums, they started discussing this about 2 weeks ago (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=309600).

Comment: @ajgringo619 yes, thank you. I did happen across that thread earlier; however even though mint is based on ubuntu, they're different enough. But ya - seriously - what are they thinking? Xfinity's streaming service has been just as blissfully ignorant to the fact that web apps (especially streaming services) should be platform agnostic.

Comment: heh - somebody downvoted me. How very mature. If there is one thing in this world that's worse than web development that ignores platform agnosticism it's the StackOverflow downvote-mob mentality. If you're going to drop a downvote - leave a comment with a logical and well thought out reason as to why. Is this not an Ubuntu forum? Does this issue not seem Ubuntu and/or Linux related? If not, please - elucidate.

Comment: I have the same problem with Cox Cable; even my Windows 10 VM can't use their Contour site. Thankfully I can get all the main channels I want via Linux. Btw, I seriously doubt this has anything to do with Ubuntu specifically, but Linux in general.

Comment: I'm like 99% sure this is a more general linux issue; but the only reference point I have is from an Ubuntu machine at this point.

Comment: Your question on Linux & Unix SE has a much nicer tone than this one. "*Are you going to downvote me and close my question as well?*" seems much more like a rant; it's an unwise way to ask for help from a volunteer community.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is cross-posted at Unix and Linux Stack Exchange. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Comment: @user535733 meh, really don't care too much anymore. I've seen plenty of sincere questions get slaughtered by the infamous SE downvote squad - obviously even some of my own. Volunteers are fine, but you know as well as I that it only takes one first downvote to start a cascade of downvotes. It's a lemming fest and it's a serious bottleneck for people who are honestly seeking help.
I also vote to close this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think may be going on with CBS - and this is just my theory.  Widevine is the Digital Rights Management that the major streaming services use.  It has three security levels.  L3 is basic.  L1 is advanced.  There is also something called Verified Media Path in Widevine.  As I understand it (correct me if I’m wrong), VMP requires code that protects the video stream from being monitored.  Microsoft, Apple, and many devices and smart TVs have added this code to their OSs.  Linux has not, and from what I’ve read, apparently will not be doing so anytime soon.  Linux wants everything to be open and accessible.  In Linux the video stream can be accessed and recorded.  This obviously isn’t going to fly with content providers as all video content moves online.

My guess is that previously CBS was accepting basic L3 security and subsequent to January 6, 2020 it requires VMP.  Although, some things like CBS Short Treks still will play on Linux.  Perhaps they aren’t that concerned about shorter or older content.  Amazon Prime will still accept L3.  That’s why going to Prime first and then accessing CBS through it will work on Linux.  Also if one creates a Windows Virtual Machine in Linux and then uses Chrome in the VM to go to CBS it will work, because Microsoft and Google work together to implement VMP in Windows.

Older devices or televisions that cannot implement the required code are affected as well.  There are many complaints at:

https://sitedown.co/cbs-all-access

CBS says that they no longer support Linux.  It’s sort of the other way around.  Linux isn’t supporting CBS (and others) that will be using higher security in Widevine.  I don’t believe CBS is actively blocking Linux just for the heck of it; I’d say they’re rejecting anything that can’t comply with certain security requirements.

I think it is doubtful that the situation will change for the better any time soon.  In fact it will probably get worse.  More and more providers will start requiring L1/VMP and if your OS doesn’t support it you will be out of luck streaming from those sources.

Comment: VMP isn't really much about code in itself. It's about having an approved signature (which can give some guarantee on the integrity of the display chain, which in turn is what more or less protects the content). And the thing isn't *in opposition* to L3/L1. It's in **addition** to them. Also it's not even really much about linux. Both Intel and AMD drivers support HDCP nowadays. Simply put, google still didn't bothered to validate the required bureaucracy or whatnot.